# Uploading Entity Framework to Team Foundation (Source control)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I am trying to upload my project to TFF via source control under Visual Studio 2015. Everything worked great, until I actually added Entity Framework via NuGet Package.

Suddenly, when I click on the whole solution and try to **Check In** changes, it fails on the following error:

`Could not find file '..Project Path\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0.deleteme'.`

I have tried to uninstall Entity Framework, Downgrade, Upgrade, but none of that has actually worked.

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file's name has 'deleteme' in it the solution is always easy: Find the file in your pending changes and right click 'Undo...'. This will remove it from your pending changes, but other than that it won't actually do anything since it's already been deleted.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: You're welcome, tfs can be a real pain sometimes :-)